# AWS-CDK ECS Fargate LoadBalancer listening on port 80 with target group mapping to container port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I've been trying to build a simple ECS Fargate infrastructure using the CDK to learn ECS and its components. The web server exposes port 8081, service SG ingress rule allows all TCP from ALB SG, ALB SG allows connection on PORT 80 - later changed to all TCP for testing. ALB has a listener on port 80 – later also on port 8081 – which forwards traffic to the Target Group on HTTP:8081, fargate tasks are automatically registered, health checks are passing.

Everything seems to be set up the right way, however, when going to `[alb-dns].com` I get nothing – not even a 504 – DNS just cannot be found. But when I go with `[alb-dns].com:8081` it serves me the "hello world" from the webserver. This works regardless of whether my Target Group is on HTTP:8081 or HTTP:80.

I tried an old [github/stackoverflow](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/issues/267#issuecomment-719526100) solution of passing a listener as port mapping to a container, but that doesn't work anymore – type mismatch.

What am I missing here?

Code:

```js
this.cluster = new Cluster(this, 'exanubes-cluster', {
            vpc: props.vpc,
            clusterName: 'exanubes-cluster',
            containerInsights: true,
            enableFargateCapacityProviders: true,
        })

        const albSg = new SecurityGroup(this, 'SecurityGroupLoadBalancer', {
             vpc: props.vpc,
             allowAllOutbound: true
         })
         albSg.addIngressRule(Peer.anyIpv4(), Port.allTcp())

         const alb = new ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'alb', {
             vpc: props.vpc,
             loadBalancerName: 'exanubes-ecs-application-LB',
             internetFacing: true,
             securityGroup: albSg,
             http2Enabled: false,
             deletionProtection: false
         })

         const listener = alb.addListener('http listener', {
             port: 80,
             open: true
         })

         const targetGroup = listener.addTargets('tcp-listener-target', {
             targetGroupName: 'tcp-target-ecs-service',
             protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
             protocolVersion: ApplicationProtocolVersion.HTTP1,
             port: CONTAINER_PORT
         })

         const taskDefinition = new FargateTaskDefinition(this, 'fargate-task-definition');

          taskDefinition.addContainer('web-server', {
             image: EcrImage.fromEcrRepository(props.repository),
         }).addPortMappings({
              containerPort: CONTAINER_PORT
          })

         const securityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, 'http-sg', {
             vpc: props.vpc,
         })

         securityGroup.addIngressRule(Peer.securityGroupId(albSg.securityGroupId), Port.allTcp(), 'Allow inbound connections from ALB')
         const fargateService = new FargateService(this, 'fargate-service', {
             cluster: this.cluster,
             assignPublicIp: true,
             taskDefinition,
             capacityProviderStrategies: [
                 {
                     capacityProvider: "FARGATE_SPOT",
                     weight: 0,
                 },
                 {
                     capacityProvider: "FARGATE",
                     weight: 1
                 }
             ],
             securityGroups: [securityGroup],
         })
         targetGroup.addTarget(fargateService)
```

PS: I know of `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` but I wanted to build it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this example in the source code `.../aws_cdk/aws_ecs/__init__.py` should help

```
    Example::

    # cluster: ecs.Cluster
    # task_definition: ecs.TaskDefinition
    # vpc: ec2.Vpc
    
    service = ecs.FargateService(self, "Service", cluster=cluster, task_definition=task_definition)
    
    lb = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(self, "LB", vpc=vpc, internet_facing=True)
    listener = lb.add_listener("Listener", port=80)
    service.register_load_balancer_targets(
        container_name="web",
        container_port=80,
        new_target_group_id="ECS",
        listener=ecs.ListenerConfig.application_listener(listener,
            protocol=elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS
        )
    )
```

Edit: the above did not work for me, but this did

```
        listener.add_targets('tcp-target-group',
                           protocol=ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
                           target_group_name="my-target",
                           targets=[service.load_balancer_target(
                               container_name=container.container_name,
                               container_port=CONTAINER_PORT
                           )],
                           )
```